# How to configure Babel to transform only React JSX tags into JS?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jsx

I'm using React with Webpack and babel. I configured app by myself (not using create-react-app) but babel uses default configuration that translates es6 to es5. I only want to transform JSX to JS. Really, I only need support of the latest versions of macOS and iOS Safari and not any other browsers. Is it possible to configure webpack and/or babel like that?

Comment: If you only want to convert JSX/React, then just enable the [`@babel/preset-react`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) preset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) said, [@babel/preset-react](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) only transforms JSX elements to JS. Some legacy components (like function expressions and vars) are still in the bundle, but it's because of how Babel works.